# body-parser.js not found when deploying

Tags: parse-platform

I got this error when I try to deploy node.js files.

```
Updated failed with Could not triggers. The error was Error: Module body-parser.js not found
```

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
});

app.listen();
```

I have npm install body-parser in my local machine. What should I do in order for Parse to recognize this module?

Answer (score 4):

Parse's express framework is not a full node.js app. So you cannot directly use node.js packages that aren't supported by Parse.
Try this one instead,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
});

app.listen();
```

[Reference Docs @ Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/express.html)

Comment: So, do I need to deploy to Parse every time I have made changes? Is there any convenient way for us to test in our local first before deploying?

Comment: You can use `parse develop AppName` to have it listen for file changes and just deploy deltas for quicker testing.